# How to add multiple instances of a CKEditor plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, instance, multiple-instances

I have a CKEditor plugin that creates a dropdown menu to the toolbar menu.

I need to have two or more of these for different dropdown options.
I don't want a dropdown menu which includes both fruits and vegetables but on contrary separate dropdown for each.

For now I've created a json that represents  properties for different dropdown menus.
Could I iterate this json to produce multiple dropdowns?

Comment: Is there any code you tried ?

Comment: I don't know where to begin so I didn't provide any code. Plugin is "strinsert".